# Linq XML checking to see element is in list

Tags: xml, linq, list

I am somewhat new to Linq XML and enjoy a lot of this. I am currently stuck on the following situation.

1. I have an intArray {1, 2, 3}
2. I want to obtain values of an element --> i.e. a enumeration.
3. Now I want to make sure that none of the elements in 2 are in the list 1,2,3 or the method will return false.

So:

1 `int[] id={151, 150};`

2

```
var anonymousSurveyResponses =
    from response in doc.Descendants(ns + "SurveyResponse")
    select new
              {
                  QuestionId = response.Element(ns + "intQuestionId").Value,
              };
```

What I want to do is find the annonymous.surveyResponses.QuestionID contains ANY of the elements in the array initialed in 1.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if(anonymousSurveyResponses.Any(x => id.Contains(x))
{
    // Return true since there's an element in id that matches an
    // element of anonymousSurveyResponses (x in this case).

    // Do your logic here.
}
```

[LINQ Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx).